# Rails whenever is adding backslash to runner command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cron, whenever

I am using [Whenever gem](https://github.com/javan/whenever) for cron task.

This is my schedule.rb file"

```
set :output, "#{path}/log/cron.log"
set :environment, 'develop'

every 2.minutes do
  runner "User.say_hello"
end
```

but it writes to the crontab with extra back-slashes and it is not working

```
script/rails runner -e develop '\''User.say_hello'\''
```

But It should be like that?

```
script/rails runner -e develop 'User.say_hello'
```

**UPDATE**

This is my class method in User class

```
def self.say_hello
   Mailer.cooperation("current_user").deliver!
end
```

It raises this error

```
You did not specify how you would like Rails to report deprecation notices for your develop environment, please set config.active_support.deprecation to :log, :notify or :stderr at config/environments/develop.rb
    /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@socposts/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
        from /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@socposts/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
        from /home/sunloverz/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@socposts/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
```

I have already added

```
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log
```

In the cron log it prints and doesn't send mail,
 but `Mailer.cooperation("current_user").deliver!` is sending mails from rails console

Database.yml

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: utf8
  reconnect: false
  database: project_db
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: lkjsdEEdfd
  host: localhost
```

Comment: What do you mean by, "it is not working?"  How is it not working?  Also, are you asking us if the last code you show us is correct?

Comment: if you've already tried running `User.say_hello` in the console and it is working fine, try running `whenever` in the terminal and copy paste the command being ran by cron.  You'll most probably see the error there.  also, check out the logs.

Comment: backslashes are fine. i was having an issue with writing to the log file because of permissions of the bin/rails script. Check it has the right permissions (should be 761). I added this to my restart task in capistrano  `execute :chmod, 'u+x', "#{release_path}/bin/rails"`

Comment: didn't see your edit on time, my previous comment is not useful...But as is written in your log file you should specify `config.active_support.deprecation = :log` in your `environment/develop.rb` file. Have you tried it?

Comment: @sissy yes, I have tried

Comment: what about your database.yml? how is it configured?

Comment: @sissy Added my database.yml, everything works fine except whenever

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using different names for the same environment:

In your database.yml you're calling it `development`

whereas you're running your whenever task with environment called `develop`

they have to match.

It's normal everything is working fine til now, because the default name Rails uses is development, so if you're not specifying any environment when migrating, it'll use development by default.
But you're running the whenever task with develop environment, which has not actually any db associated.

hope it helps.